# How to know if controller implements mixin

Tags: ember.js

How can you know if a controller implements a specific mixin?

Ignore this text, it's only added so this thing stopped telling me the question was invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
App.MyMixin.detect(myControllerInstance);
```

This will only work on instance, though, not on class.